# An issue with restricting access to a cloud function based on API key through Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I try to restrict access to Google cloud function by defining API KEY in openapi.yaml

```
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
security:
  - api_key: []
securityDefinitions:
  api_key:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "mot"
    in: "query"  
paths:
  /:
    get:
      summary: Greet a user
      operationId: hello
```

Deployment steps:

```
1. gcloud run deploy apikeytst1 --image="gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime-serverless:2" --allow-unauthenticated --platform managed --project=xxxx
2. gcloud endpoints services deploy apikeytst.yaml --project xxxx
3. ./gcloud_build_image -s apikeytst1-yyyyyyyyy-ew.a.run.app -c 2020-10-08r0 -p xxxx
4. gcloud run deploy apikeytst1 --image="gcr.io/xxxxx/endpoints-runtime-serverless:apikeytst1-yyyyyyyyyy-ew.a.run.app-2020-10-08r0" --allow-unauthenticated --platform managed  --project=xxxx
```

But anyone can invoice the function without the key.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you followed the [information](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/restricting-api-access-with-api-keys) provided by google in setting up the Swagger specification. It probably has to do something with your cloud endpoints deployment or permissions. I would advise you to go through all the cloud endpoints [steps](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions#deploy_esp) again carefully. If you correctly deployed cloud endpoints as a wrapper around your cloud function, you should not be able to invoke the cloud function directly. Instead, use the cloud endpoints endpoint with an API key as a query parameter. One crucial step is to remove the allUsers invoker permissions from your cloud function and add the following:

```
gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding FUNCTION_NAME \
   --region FUNCTION_REGION \
   --member "serviceAccount:ESP_PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com" \
   --role "roles/cloudfunctions.invoker" \
   --project FUNCTIONS_PROJECT_ID
```

Comment: I performed all steps according to the Google documentation for several different endpoints. API key restriction does not work

Comment: Wierd, because I did the exact same thing and it worked all the time! Please update your question with the exact steps you followed, so I can help.

Comment: I understood from Google support that there is an issue here https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-limitations#api_key_definition_limitations but did not understand how to deal with it

Comment: Is it possible to change "mot" to "key" or "api_key"?

Answer (score 0):

Google requests that the first key must be a key with the name "key" or "api_key".
After that (on the second etc positions), we can add keys with arbitrary names.